# Capture HTML from WebView as an Image?

Tags: android, android-webview

The WebView has 2 deprecated methods that were used for capturing the content as an Image:

```
capturePicture()
setPictureListener()
```

As these are deprecated, what is now available to capture the webview content as an image?

Is this the correct way now:

```
public void takePicture() {
    WebView webView = new WebView(context);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getContentHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(b);

            view.draw(c);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using `WebView.draw()` is the correct way. However, doing that from `onPageFinished` does not guarantee that there is anything actually displayed, as this event is fired when the page resources have been loaded, and the page can use some JS code which actually displays stuff.

The right approach is to use `PictureListener.onNewPicture()` callback (despite its deprecated status). This event is still fired when WebView has drawn something, but as the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.PictureListener.html) says, doesn't actually provide the picture -- for that, you have to call `WebView.draw()`.

Also, be aware that if your app is targeting L API level or above, you need to call `WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw()` prior to creating any WebViews in order to make it to draw the entire contents of WebView onto the canvas, see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw()).

Things will got better with the M release, where a new callback called `VisualStateListener` is added (see [this doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Pg_LusbzBNfghnK83IfJ43iZOBc7LI1fp669CiVhcN8/edit#heading=h.njjfndgjj3e5)). You can check it out in the [preview SDK](https://developer.android.com/preview/download.html).